# ¿Hay alguna manera de evitar que las animaciones css se vean borrosas en Chrome?

Tags: html, css, animate.css

Tengo un problema con animaciones en Chrome, estoy haciendo animaciones en CSS que se activan al cargar la página, pero en Chrome a veces se hace borrosa. Adjunto un par de imágenes y mi código:

Esta es la imagen borrosa, mientras la animación se activa
[image: Animación borrosa]

Esta es la página cuando la animación ya está completa
[image: Animación completa]

```
HTML:
<div class="menuback">
  <img src="img/menuback.svg" alt="">
</div>

CSS:
.menuback {
  width: 4.297%;
  height: 3%; 
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  right: -2%;
  bottom: 48.6%;
  transform: scale(12.9) translateX(0) translateY(0);
  animation-name: blowmenuback;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
.menuback img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% !important; 
}

@keyframes blowmenuback {
  from {transform: scale(0) translateX(0) translateY(0);}
  to {transform: scale(12.9) translateX(0) translateY(0);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hola para evitar esto no muestres la pagina hasta que este cargada del todo esto lo puedes lograr con `javascript`:

ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    body{display:none;} /* configuramos el documento para que no se vea hasta
                     terminar la carga se suele usar el mismo color de fondo o un loader*/
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0923/9476/products/JIM_0288-Edit.jpg?v=1555559952" alt="big img">
</script>
    function load() {
      document.querySelector("body").style.display ="initial";
      console.log("load complete!");
    }
    window.onload = load; // cuando el documento este cargado se llama la funcion load!
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> **nota:** puedes agrupar el codigo dentro de un `<div class="container-load">` para evitar no mostrar todo el body!